# Alpha animation works, then does not work

Tags: java, android

My app is about users picking three buttons: Sad, Happy and Confuse. If they click the Sad button, the image changes into a sad emoji. If they click the Happy button, happy emoji is displayed. Simple.

But, when I run my app, and I click any of the buttons, the alpha animation works. If I then click another button, the alpha animation does not work anymore. The alpha animation only works once. The alpha animation is only for the images.

Here's my Java code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Happy_Btn = findViewById(R.id.Happy_Btn);
        Sad_Btn = findViewById(R.id.Sad_Btn);
        Confuse_Btn = findViewById(R.id.Confuse_Btn);
        Feeling_txtView = findViewById(R.id.Feeling_txtView);
        Face_Img = findViewById(R.id.Face_Img);

        Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0f, 1.0f);
        animation.setDuration(2000);

        Feeling_txtView.setText("You are feeling happy!");
        Happy_Btn.setEnabled(false);

        Sad_Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Sad_Btn.setEnabled(false);
                Happy_Btn.setEnabled(true);
                Confuse_Btn.setEnabled(true);

                Feeling_txtView.setText("You are feeling sad...");
                Face_Img.setAnimation(animation);
                Face_Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.sad);
            }
        });

        Happy_Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Sad_Btn.setEnabled(true);
                Happy_Btn.setEnabled(false);
                Confuse_Btn.setEnabled(true);

                Feeling_txtView.setText("You are feeling happy!");
                Face_Img.setAnimation(animation);
                Face_Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.happyface);
            }
        });

        Confuse_Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Sad_Btn.setEnabled(true);
                Happy_Btn.setEnabled(true);
                Confuse_Btn.setEnabled(false);

                Feeling_txtView.setText("You are feeling confused?");
                Face_Img.setAnimation(animation);
                Face_Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.confuse);
            }
        });
    }
```

(EDIT)
I made few changes to my code and then when I run it, my issue is solved! But I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it. What I did was I first **cut** these two lines:

```
Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0f, 1.0f);
animation.setDuration(2000);
```

and then **paste** them into each buttons (Sad, Happy and Confuse)
My app works the way I wanted it to be.

Comment: while you might be learning about _using_ android studio, your code (and your question) won't be any different in another IDE, so you're learning android, not android studio. there's no need to use the android studio tag or make any reference to it here, just use the `android` tag, unless you're asking about a feature of the IDE specifically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should renew AlphaAnimation

you do it is the right